# sfdx force:source:pull Entity of type 'CustomApplication' named 'Case' cannot be found

Tags: salesforcedx

I have a scratch org that I'm trying to implement the support console with.  When I try to pull the code using sfdx, I'm getting the following error:

`Entity of type 'CustomApplication' named 'Case' cannot be found`

I tried putting `CustomApplication/**` and `CustomApplication/Case` in the *.forceignore* file and tried to pull and still get the same error.

Has anyone had to deal with something like this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a bug I feel somewhere in the sfdx cli and one needs to bring it attention to Salesforce on this.

The following is a workaround that did actually work for me .

- I created an application named 'case' in my scratch org
- Run `sfdx force:source:pull.
- Add the folder path of the application in .gitignore and in .forceignore files.

Note that with this workaround I was able to get past this issue.However it is definitely a bug in salesforce CLI which I request you raise a support case.

**Update**

Any thing you want to exclude when you run force:source:pull you can do so by deleting the Member from Source Member object.

Use Developer console to execute below query

```
Select Id, MemberName From SourceMember Where MemberType = 'CustomApplication
```

and Delete it in the Dev console.

Comment: Thank you so much Mohith for giving this a try.  I actually ended up doing this as well and was able to get past my issue.

Comment: This seems to be happening again. I just experienced it except with "Contact". I created a SFDX project, created a LWC, made it available for Contact record pages. I created a Contact flexipage, added the LWC for it, and activated the flexipage as org-wide default. When I tried pulling source I got:  Entity of type 'CustomApplication' named 'Contact' cannot be found

Comment: @Charles T it's better to report it to the sfdx-cli repo

Comment: Thanks. Issue link: https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/205 and dcarroll included the suggestion of deleting the `SourceMember` entry responsible for the error.

Comment: Just a quick note on the "update" section; that query requires the Tooling API checkbox to be checked if running from the Dev console's Query Editor.

Answer (score 7):

Just happen to me too. Seems like its a [known Issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?Id=a1p3A000001SjPn) - Only way I managed to remove this error was remove/delete the SourceMember.

`sfdx force:data:soql:query -q "Select Id, MemberName From SourceMember Where MemberType = 'CustomApplication'" -t`

Then Delete with the result Id.
`sfdx force:data:record:delete -s SourceMember -i 0MZ1** -t -u orgAlias`

Comment: thanks, this worked for me

Answer (score 4):

An alternate (as the OP was attempting) would be to add to the `.forceignore` file.
I *believe* this is the entry that's needed (though the syntax is confusing and case-sensitive... with next-to-zero docs)

```
Case.CustomApplication
```

Comment: Thanks for following up Todd!

Comment: It seems this has been fixed now but if not then we need to raise it again.

Comment: @MohithShrivastava What is the final solution for it? Did you get any? Or still we have to query and delete the source member or create an app in salesforce, then pull and then delete?  Please share the forceignore details if this can be skipped

Comment: What I know is this should no more be issue.It is fixed with latest version of cli

Comment: what is the exact line here ? **/Case.CustomApplication ?

Comment: This does not appear to be fixed; the known issue linked in another answer doesn't show it as fixed, and I'm still seeing the same issue on cli version `sfdx-cli@7.46.3`.  I've tried several variations and nothing works.  Any get the `.forceignore` approach to work?

Answer (score 4):

After trying many variations, I've found that `CustomApplication` **does not** follow the [documented pattern](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_exclude_source.htm?search_text=forceignore) of `<api name>.<metadata type>` for any variation of capitalization, including

```
Lead.CustomApplication
Lead.customApplication
Lead.customapplication
lead.customapplication
# grasping at straws
*Lead.CustomApplication*
```

However, using `app` as the metadata type name **does** work, e.g.,

```
Lead.app
```

Tested with cli version `sfdx-cli@7.46.3`.

Comment: Yes... I believe for the stuff you want to ignore that is remote you can use the `<api name>.<extension-as-would-be-in-the-repo>, (less any "-meta.xml") e.g if you had a custom application in the repo it would be in a file called "Lead.app-meta.xml", and could be ignored with "Lead.app"

Answer (score 4):

I ran onto the following error:

```
ERROR running force:source:pull:  Entity of type 'ProfileSessionSetting' named 'HR2day_Standaardgebruiker_profileSessionSetting1615531712750' cannot be found
```

The mechanism suggested by @sfdxbomb did not solve the problem. I resolved it by hacking the file `.sfdx/orgs/test-k8gkrkaylwvt@example.com/maxRevision.json` and removing the sections mentioning the entity.

Comment: Same for me - thanks

Comment: Your fix worked for me Oscar. Thanks!